# Check $f$ and $f_x$ are bounded or unbounded?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$ for $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$. Then which of the following is correct option?
1.$f_x$ and $f$ are bounded.
2.$f_x$ and $f$ are unbounded.
3.$f_x$ is bounded and $f$ is unbounded.
4.$f_x$ is unbounded and $f$ is bounded.
My attempt:I got $f_x=\frac{2xy^3}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$. As $f$ is not defined for $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$, can we say $f$ is unbounded?
As $(x,y)$ approches $(0,0)$, $f$ is not defined.How to check boundedness of $f_x?$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $2|xy|\leq x^2+y^2$. Hence
$$|f_x(x,y)|=\frac{2|xy|y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\leq \frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2}\leq 1.$$
What about $f(x,y)$? Hint: consider the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x,x)$.

P.S. Note that 
$$|f(x,y)|=\frac{|x|\cdot|xy|}{x^2+y^2}\leq \frac{|x|}{2}$$
and therefore $f(x,y)$ goes to zero as  $(x,y)\to (0,0)$. This means that $f$ is bounded in a neighbourhood of the origin.

Comment: @ASHWINI SANKHE Any further doubt?